# Can a conditional LINQ query be combined into one that runs every time?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've got two queries used to filter down a list of data.  The main part runs every time, and in normal situations should cut the total number of results down to at most a dozen or two.  When I'm editing a `Foo` object instead of creating a new one, I also want to remove the copy saved in the DB from the set of data I'm working on.

I'm currently using an if statement and a second query to strip it out.  Is there a way to combine the condition and second query into the first one?

```
IEnumerable<Foo> myFoos = bar.GetFoos()
    .Where(f => f.Value1 == value1 && f.Value2 == value2);


if (editFoo != null)
   myFoos = myFoos.Where(f => f.ID != editFoo.ID);
```

When I try the queries suggested by sehe or Dan Seaver, and call `.ToList()` on `myFoos` I get an exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Foo'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context
```

I created dummy objects that contained every property in my un-munged query and it ran without error, so I'm leaning towards suspecting the problem is that the Entity Framework doesn't understand the null checks in the proposed queries and is barfing on them.   **The entity framework was to blame; without it either solution would work as written.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean logic to the rescue.

```
IEnumerable<Foo> myFoos = bar.GetFoos()
    .Where(f => 
        (f.Value1 == value1) && 
        (f.Value2 == value2) &&
        ((editFoo == null) || (f.ID != editFoo.ID)));
```

The thing that makes it work is [shortcut evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `(editFoo == null) || (f.ID != editFoo.ID)`?

Comment: @DanSeaver: oops classic mistake. Fixed

Comment: That looks like it should have worked, but I get the exception:  Unable to create a constant value of type 'Foo'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: @DanNeely: you have unrelated problem there. You could update the question with your current version, so we might help in spot it

Comment: The only thing I munged were the actual types/member names; and the old queries do work.  Foo is an Entity Framework object, and the exception doesn't occur until I try and enumerate myFoos (either in the debugger, or via ToList()).

Comment: @sehe Turns out it was the EntityFramework barfing.  When I carved `(editFoo == null)` out into a temp variable and modified the line to `((isNull) || (f.ID != editFoo.ID)));` the query ran without error.

Comment: @DanNeely: just be aware that `isNull` will be captured _by reference_ inside the lambda now, and that may not do what you expect. Then again, it may very well do exactly what you expect depending on the lifetime of isNull and when you update it!

Comment: `isNull` is a temp assigned immediately before the query, and never used for anything afterwards.  `editFoo` isn't modified at any point until after `myFoos` goes out of scope.  In that case I don't think any of the gotchas with lazy evaluation could come into play.

Comment: @DanSeaver: correct. You might want to make that explicit (by calling .ToList() on the enumerable?); that will also make tools like Resharper less prone to warn you about _'possible multiple enumeration of `myFoos`'_

Comment: @sehe I don't think I've ever seen that warning before, is it new to ReSharper 6?  (I'm stuck on 5.1.)  What I would get is several rounds of *parameter type can be changed to IEnumeral* warnings if I switched it all to Lists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5237/discussion-between-sehe-and-dan-neely)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> myFoos = bar.GetFoos()
    .Where(f => f.Value1 == value1 &&
           f.Value2 == value2 && 
           ((editFoo != null) ? (f.ID != editFoo.ID) : true) );
```

Comment: I tried your version but I got the same error as with sehe's.